# Receiving 403 when Google Classrom list courseWork API for a teacher enrolled in the course

Tags: google-classroom

I am calling the Google Classroom API GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWork

on behalf of a teacher who is enrolled in the given courseId. The API is returning `HttpError 403` when requesting

```
https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/courseId/courseWork?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission">
```

This teacher has the correct scopes to my knowledge to call this API 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly'

I'm able to get the course information and list both the teachers and students without any issues. I'm unclear on why this endpoint is returning permission denied.

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample of your code (with no sensitive data) to figure out where this issue might be coming from? Also, try to use the method [list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) for that teacher to see if that course is listed there.